# Python subprocess.PIPE redirect to file

Tags: python, subprocess

I have the following piece of code. *myprg* has to run after my script exits. But before exiting, I would like to wait for *mystring* to be emitted by *myprg* and then redirect rest of the stderr messages to *mylogfile* and then exit. Is this possible at all? I tried the following and the python script does not exit. Where am I going wrong?

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(myprg, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in iter(proc.stderr.readline,'')
if check_string in line:
    break

fh = open (mylogfile,'w')

proc.stderr = fh.fileno()
```

EDIT: I have temporarily worked around this problem by making  *myprg* to emit *check_string* to stdout. This is less than optimal, but works for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't you call `proc.communicate()` for the script to exit?

Comment: This doesn't work either. I can get my code to exit even without proc.communicate(), but I am unable to redirect any further stderr messages to a file on disk.